# Portable XAMPP Alternative

Tags: php, webserver, xampp

I was using XAMPP portable (for USB flash drives) for a long time. The creator team is no longer supporting/updating the project, which is not even compatible with the latest PHP version.

Is there any alternative all-in-one, portable web-server (like XAMPP) with latest updates?

Comment: Why do you need a portable version? Sounds like you just need to install the stack yourself and blame yourselrf.

Comment: @PeeHaa Oh.. At my work, nearly all ports are blocked. I can only work with local webserver. And I was using XAMPP as webserver on USB flash drive. Now, it doens't fit my needs. Software is old.

Comment: Obvious local is local. I.e. why does it matter why you are using some one-click stack or install it yourself?

Comment: @PeeHaa I don't want to keep traces of my projects on office computers.

Comment: You naughty naughty boy/girl. Just install the stack on your own server. And upload your personal project to that.

Comment: @PeeHaa I can't understand you. I said all ports are BLOACKED EXCEPT HTTP/HTTPS. What do you mean by install stack? I have shared servers only, I can either use local server to test, or shared servers. I can't upload anything via ftp, because it's blocked at work. The only solution is, portable webserver. Is that clear?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13282/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-peehaa)

Answer (score 5):

[Z-WAMP](http://zwamp.sourceforge.net/) is the nicest portable WAMP I've found.

Comment: PHP 5.3.14 .. It's old too. Latest PHP is 5.4

Comment: Wow! PHP 5.4 that's old! Now get off my lawn!

Comment: It's the only actively developed portable WAMP I've found, let me know if you find another :) The latest Z-WAMP was released 2 days ago though :) http://sourceforge.net/projects/zwamp/files/

Comment: If you think the PHP 5.3 series is old, try looking for hosting providers with PHP 5.4. I guarantee you'll be disappointed.

Comment: @James You jinxed it man. Last updated: 2013.

Answer (score 4):

I've used [Uniform Server](http://www.uniformserver.com/) in the past from a portable drive. The current version ([8.5.5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/miniserver/files/Uniform%20Server/8.5.5-Coral/) at the time of writing, released 16/6/2012) has Apache 2.4.2, MySQL 5.5.25-community and PHP 5.4.4.

Answer (score 3):

How about Laragon (http://laragon.org/).

Laragon offers you a powerful but Isolated Development Environment.
It is portable and very flexible.

Install Laragon doesn't affect your Windows. You can move Laragon installation folder to another disk and Laragon still works.

Laragon now supports Memcached and Redis (optional).

Current version: 0.3 (stable)

Apache 2.4.10

MySQL (MariaDB 10.0.15)

PHP 5.6.3

Memcached 1.4.5

Redis 2.8.17

Check [Laragon](http://laragon.org) out.

Answer (score 1):

XAMPP is back in development!! As of Aug 2012 they released a new version that has all the latest Apache, PHP, and such. [Check it out!](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also check "Comparison of WAMPs on Wikipedia":
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs

All here listed WAMPs and more are included.

Comment: This wikipedia page has been deleted now. Which is a shame.

Comment: The old deleted page can still be found on the web archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20121018222942/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs

Answer (score 0):

[WTServer](http://wtserver.wtriple.com/) - Nginx MariaDB Redis Php development stack for Windows

- updated regulary
- The installer produces a portable folder.

Current Package contains:

```
Nginx 1.11.7 web server
MariaDB 10.1.19 database server, mysql replacement (32/64bit)
Redis 3.2 Cache/NoSql, memcached alternative (64bit)
Php 5.6.29 & PHP 7.0.14 & PHP 7.1.0 scripting language (32/64bit)
XDebug, GeoIP, Gender PHP Extensions
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an active internet connection and docker installed on your development machine, you could give **[devilbox](https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox)** a try.

It is a modern docker-based lamp stack offering various features:

- Start up any php version (php 5.4 - php 7.1 or even hhvm)
- Start up and sql version (mysql 5.5 - mysql 8 or all mariadb versions)
- auto vhost creation
- auto DNS
- Email catch-all
- and many others
- phpMyAdmin
- Adminer
- OpcacheGUI

https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox

[image: devilbox]